# How to convert a substring in a string to uppercase without using replace() function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have:

```
def my_replace(s1,sub):
    # ?
```

I need to check if `sub` is in `s1` and if it is I need to convert the sub to uppercase in the string.

For example:

```
s1 = "mouse is useful thing"
sub = "use"
```

prints:

```
moUSE is USEful thing
```

Comment: You changed your question's description to not use replace function after the answers were given with `replace` and then you downvoted the ones which used `replace`? If you have a requirement, comment it on the answers, don't downvote them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do it with the combination of `split()` and `join()` functions.

```py
def my_replace(s1,sub):
    temp = s1.split(sub)
    s1 = sub.upper().join(temp)
    return s1
print(my_replace('mouse is useful thing','use'))
```

Output : moUSE is USEful thing

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.upper()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) with [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace). See below:

```
def my_replace(s1,sub):
   return s1.replace(sub, sub.upper())
```

For your example:

```
s1 = "mouse is useful thing"
sub = "use"
```

Output will be:

```
>>> my_replace(s1,sub)

'moUSE is USEful thing'
```

Comment: yes i see that , its working but I didn't want to use replace() function

Answer (score 1):

Because you specified that you cannot use `str.replace()`, this solution will work for you without that method:

```py
def my_replace(s1, sub):
    temp = list(s1) 
    for idx,e in enumerate(s1):
        if e == sub[0] and s1[idx:idx+len(sub)] == sub:
            temp[idx:idx+len(sub)] = sub.upper()

    return "".join(temp)
```

This function first creates a temporary list, `temp`, from the string `s1`. This is so we can easily alter the values of a list (`str` is immutable, `list` is not). We can then parallelly iterate through the indices (`idx`) and elements (`e`) of `s1`. When the iteration gets to the first letter of `sub`, it considers the next n elements, where n is the length of `sub`. If the substring is equal to `sub`, it changes the elements in the list that match that substring to the uppercase of that element. At the end of the function, it returns a joined `temp`, using `list.join()`. Your result is as follows:

```py
res = my_replace(s1, sub)
```

```py
"moUSE is USEful thing"
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
s.replace(input_string, input_string.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

The string.replace function lets you do that.

An example of it's use:

```
>>> 'A man can plan, but a canal cannot'.replace('can', 'bun')
'A man bun plan, but a bunal bunnot'
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried without replace, it turned out very similar with a friend next to it =)

```
def upper_sub(source, sub):
    len_sub = len(sub)
    result = list(source)
    for i, t in enumerate(source):
        if source[i: i+len_sub] == sub:
            result[i: i+len_sub] = sub.upper()

    return ''.join(result)
```

Comment: im begginer actually and don't know some of the algorithm you wrote . thanks for helping